# Windows 8 will not boot after set virtual memory to 9999MB

Tags: windows-8, boot, virtual-memory

To increase the performance of an ASUS X551M I increased the virtual memory 9999MB. In the past I would determine the max available virtual memory by typing in 9999. I expected to see something like "ERROR: Max virtual memory setting is 4092MB". When no such error was produced I assumed that Windows 8 could handle 9GB+ of virtual memory, applied the setting, and restarted the computer.

Now Windows 8 will not boot and system restore attempts have failed. I tried resetting the virtual memory from the command prompt, that also failed.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This a 32 or 64 bit installation

Comment: It is a 64 bit install.

Comment: If it's a 64-bit why would you think it was going to be limited to only 4GB of virtual memory?

Comment: I haven't used a windows machine since XP. In my previous experience 4GB was always the limit. I anticipated that it may not be. I'm still concerned by the fact that the machine is no longer booting after a Virtual Memory increase.

Comment: It was the limit because windows XP is a 32 bit installation.  When you say it won't boot what exactly is happening ?

Comment: I'm asking the owner of the computer and they are now less sure about whether the OS is 32 or 64.

Comment: On reboot it goes into system recovery and fails to recover the system.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to Refresh the system that will keep personal files but will require all programs to be installed again

Comment: Windows 8 has no virtual memory limit that can be set. Are you talking about the page file size?